# JVM is not releasing the virtual memroy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

My web application is throwing OOM errors. It was given 25GB memory. Application was loaded tested and we see thet memory is ramping up. But I expect the JVM to release the memory after full gc. How come JVM is not releasing the virtual memory even after the application is used.

**Here are the JVM settings:**

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:/logs/gcc.log 
-XX:MaxPermSize=96m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseCompressedStrings
-Xmx30g
```

**Here is the "top" command output:**

```
top - 02:09:42 up 117 days,  5:24,  4 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
Tasks: 140 total,   1 running, 139 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  62167808k total, 60854992k used,  1312816k free,    73444k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free, 17789504k cached
```

```
PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
17206 java     20   0 55.1g  40g  12m S  0.3 68.2 298:41.08 java
```

**Here is the "free" command output:**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      62167808   60855448    1312360          0      73592   17789532
-/+ buffers/cache:   42992324   19175484
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Please appreciate any leads to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you consider profiling your application to check if it has memory leaks?

Comment: GO run this - http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: JVisualVM is your friend.  Grab a heap dump of your app, then analyze to see what is consuming all the space - there's some reference you aren't thinking about.

Comment: You could also try [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html).

Comment: best practice for an java application is to use -Xms = -Xmx so it will take all that memory  from the start. Consider that your application runs with 15g , -Xmx =30g and then someone starts an application and your JVM will not be able to get more memory... OOM for sure

Comment: I have tried to work with visualvm, but couldn't connect to the remote VM. Is there any tool that will process the gcc logs and heap dump other than visualvm? I will try eclipse mat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all garbage collection algorithms in HotSpot JVM release virtual memory to OS after GC.

Two algorithms which can do it are

- serial `-XX:+UseSerialGC`
- G1 `-XX:+UseG1GC`

You are using CMS `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` which never releases memory to OS.

[Here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html) you can find quick summary of all GC algorithms in HotSpot.

Comment: Is there any way to find the free memory from JVM when -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC is used. Is G1 is effective compared to CMS?

Comment: JMX have plenty information about memory take a look at usage attribute at java.lang:type=MemoryPool,name=*

Comment: GC is trade of between CPU and amount of wasted memory. Even through G1 can release memory it may decide to save you some CPU cycle and not to collect old garbage until 25 GiB threshold is reached.